# JavaScript hide part of input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I hide but not delete a part of a Input text,

in my case I have a Input text which holds an ip + Name, I would like to hide the ip but Keep the Name, still the ip shall still be shown using `.val();`

```
<input type="text" id="my_url" value="192.168.3.15/name"/> <!-- hide ip -->
```

```js
$('#my_url').val();
```

Comment: This isn't possible. You can only deal with the value of an input as a whole.

Comment: you could use a hidden input.

Comment: You can hide the input `<input type="hidden" `

Comment: Does it really need to be in the same input?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas: Which doesn't remotely do what the OP asked for.

Comment: you can keep IP in hidden field and assign only name to the input field.

Comment: Use this way :  <input type="hidden" id="my_url" value="192.168.3.15/name"/>

Comment: @Dilip how would a `hidden` input still show the `/name/` part, as the OP requires?

Comment: You can "mask" the IP away by using `data-` attribute. If you need it, then pick it by using `.dataset` (or its jQuery variant)

Comment: My usual solution for this kind of problem is just to have a span and replace it with an input on click (and back on blur).

Comment: you can maintain your IP address in data-ip attribute just like this.

<input type="text" id="my_url" data-ip="192.168.3.15" value="name"/>

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in four step method.

1. Execute the following in the `blur` event.
2. Have a data attribute for the input with the original value.
3. Change the value to have your desired display value.
4. On `focus`, change back to the original value.

**Snippet** for better understanding:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#my_url").blur(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-original", this.value);
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf("/"));
    console.log(this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf("/")));
  }).focus(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("data-original") != undefined)
    this.value = $(this).attr("data-original");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_url" value="192.168.3.15/name" />
```

Update: As Denys Séguret mentioned in the comments, the above will have issues when the value is calculated. In that case, we can combine the use of `hidden` input as well:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#my_url").on("input keyup", function () {
    $("#orig_url").val(this.value);
  }).blur(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-original", this.value);
    $("#orig_url").val(this.value);
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf("/"));
    console.log(this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf("/")));
  }).focus(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("data-original") != undefined)
    this.value = $(this).attr("data-original");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_url" value="192.168.3.15/name" />
<input type="hidden" id="orig_url" />
```

And now we can use the `#orig_url`'s value in calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the only hack I could think of. It is just a demo you'll have to work it out... You create a div where you'll put the IP value, or whatever value you want to hide from the text input. That div has to have the exact same text properties as the input as it will be used to calculate the width of the text to hide.

Once we have that width, we simply apply a negative text-indent. Note that this will only have the effect of visually hiding the value, but it will still be accessible to the user... Also, do not forget to put this code in some event handler to update when needed.

```js
$('#my_url').on('change',hide);
$('#my_url').on('keyup',hide);
var widthComputer = $('<div id="widthcomputer">');
function hide(){
  var ip = $('#my_url').val().split('/')[0];
  if($('#my_url').val().split('/').length>1){
  widthComputer.text(ip+'/');
  widthComputer.appendTo('body');
  console.log(widthComputer.width());
  $('#my_url').css('text-indent',widthComputer.width()*-1);
  }else{
   $('#my_url').css('text-indent',0);
  }
}
hide();
```

```css
#widthcomputer{
    display:inline;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
    top:-500px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_url" value="192.168.3.15/name"/>
```

EDIT: I've added events and some test. The code actually hides the part left of the / (and the /) if there is a /. If not present, the full input value is shown. Just play with it, you'll see.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are expecting

```
<input type="text" id="my_url" actualvalue="192.168.3.15/name" value="/name"/>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
    console.log(document.getElementById("my_url").getAttribute("actualvalue"));
    });
</script>
```

it prints `192.168.3.15/name` on console.